# Localisation of node published date

Tags: 6, datetime, i18n-l10n

I have a Drupal site and the standard language is Danish. However the date on the nodes is rendered in English. I can't figure out why.

If i put a date field in a content type it displays correctly following my custom date format.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal provides a clean way of formatting dates any way you want throughout the entire site. Simply apply the settings that you're expecting for Danish:

[Format dates in Drupal](http://www.leveltendesign.com/blog/dustin-currie/format-dates-drupal) 6

Comment: Nothing seems to work even though I've set everything I could think of to Danish. But the problem is only with the "Content Created" dates. In Views I use the custom date format to format my date to a Danish standard (j. F Y) but the name of the month is in English - and I know everything has been translated as it works in all other date fields.

Comment: Or maybe I was wrong. It seems I had translated the strings in the Date API but not the `!long-month-name` strings. Now those strings have been translated as well - and it sort of works.